# IIS 8 Invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: ajax, wcf

Web service is already `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but why I stil got an error`Invalid HTTP status code 405`.

Ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "http://mysite/Web/Cus/Cus.svc/RegisterCus/",
      data:{"ID":1,"Name":"kiri","Sex":1},
      dataType: "json"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a cross domain call?

If Yes -

1 : Use `jsonp` instead of `json`
2 : add `crossDomain: true`

Comment: hmm web service part is not on my duty, so I just got the link, and post data to. I use chrome extension for posting , it worked :/

Comment: need your web cofig file to know what is causing this.

Comment: web config of web service?

Comment: Solved! Because of configuration of web service.

Comment: What exactly did you need to change in the configuration of the web service?